# Complex path integral with zero real part

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Is there some easy and elegant way to show that $\int_{\gamma} f^{'}(z) \bar{f}(z) dz$ has real part $0$? $f$ ist here some holomorphic function, $\bar{f}$ is a conjugate of $f$ and $\gamma$ is a closed path.
I guess that this can be proven via $f=u+iv$, $\gamma=\gamma_1+i\gamma_2$ and so on, but I would like to find less technical proof.
Thanks in advance

Comment: apply Green's theorem complex form $\oint_{\gamma} f^{'}(z) \bar{f}(z) dz = 2i \iint_{R} \frac{\partial (f^{'}(z) \bar{f}(z))}{\partial \overline{z}} dA$ and note that RHS integrand is actually $|f'(z)|^2$ so the RHS integral is $2i$ times a nonnegative number (assuming $\gamma$ positively oriented of course, otherwise the sign switches but required conclusion remains true)

Comment: Can  you please explain why the RHS integrand is $|f'|^2$?

Comment: note that $f$ hence $f'$ are holomorphic so $\frac{\partial (f^{'}(z))}{\partial \overline{z}}=0, \frac{\partial (\bar{f}(z))}{\partial \overline{z}}=\overline {f'(z)}$ and the product rule for derivatives does the rest

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: happy to be of help, no problem